# Ferns: How big can a circular sorus be?

Tags: botany, plant-anatomy, microscopy

I looked at some small ferns under the microscope. The circular sori of the ferns I looked at were less than 2 mm in diameter. The microscope I used had rather weak magnification, so I didn't get to see lots of detail. Later, I came across an image of large sori Wikipedia:

[image: Large sori on fern]

<sub>[Image source](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Large_Sori_(fern).JPG). License: public domain.</sub>

I am surprised by the size of the circular sori in the image. If I could obtain large sori such as these, I would probably be able to see more detail under weak magnification. I'm wondering:

- How big in terms of diameter can circular sori be?
- What are some species of ferns with large sori?

Answer (score 1):

Try members of the *[Asplenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asplenium)* genus, particularly the widespread *Asplenium trichomanes* or [Maidenhair fern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asplenium_trichomanes).

Without a location in the world, it will be difficult to give you a more specific answer.

Sori can be a few millimetres across, I would hazard a guess at about 5 mm diameter in my experience, but I have no scientific backing for that as a maximum dimension, and I'm only really familiar with plants in my country so can't make assumptions about other locations.